# Merge CSS files not populating

Tags: css, magento

I have recently migrated a Magento website which had been using merge_css_files successfully. On the new server however I cannot get it to work and would very much appreciate any advice on the matter. The system will create the css files in media/css but they are always blank (unpopulated). I suspect that this might be something to do with the server itself as it worked previously on the old server.

I have already toggled Merge CSS on and off, flushed the caches multiple times, deleted the files from the media/css folder, updated all file and folder permissions, checked the ownership in ftp.

Perhaps you have experienced the same or could advise on a possible solution?

Comment: How did you toggle css merge?  Have you done changes in the database for this?

Comment: It is possible to toggle css merge in one of two ways: 1) Admin backend System/Configuration/Developer/Advanced/CSS Settings or via database (e.g. myphpadmin) by finding the merge_css_files under the core_config_data table and changing the value from 1 to 0 and visa-versa.